# onGlobalLayout() may be called before the view is laid out

Tags: android

My Firebase crash reporting shows the following code malfunctions on a very small number of devices. I cannot reproduce this problem. Can anyone suggest what could be the problem? It appears the problem is that imageView.getWidth() or imageView.getHeight() return zero.

The following code is in my fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category_list, container, false);

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.categoryBackgrndImageView);

    // Set an observer that is called after the imageView is laid out
    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            //now we can retrieve the width and height
            int width = imageView.getWidth();
            int height = imageView.getHeight();

            // etc. Code here removed. It gets an asset and creates a bitmap from the
            // asset, sizing the bitmap based on the imageView width and height
        }
```

Here's the layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:menu="menu_main,menu_categories">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/categoryBackgrndImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<technology.grandma.margriver.AutoGridRecylerView
    android:id="@+id/categoryRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="330dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_category"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

My internet research seems to confirm this code is correct. Can you see anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `OnLayoutChangeListener` instead:

```
imageView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        int width = imageView.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = imageView.getMeasuredHeight();
        imageView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
    }
});
```

As `OnGlobalLayoutListener` observes the all hierarchy for layout changes, so hypothetically it could be triggered when any of the view is laid out in the hierarchy. Also `measuredWidth` and `measuredHeight` would be more likely to known at this time.